# How to capture a image from camera and display into Browser using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Am new in Angular JS. i need to capture image from Camera and display into browser using angularJS.

THanks in Advance,

Comment: https://github.com/onemightyroar/angular-camera

Answer (score 4):

Try using any of the following plugins

[webcam-directive](http://jonashartmann.github.io/webcam-directive/#/)

[ng-camera](https://github.com/bcabanes/ng-camera)

Comment: ng-camera doesn't seem to work.  The demo failed to work on my Macbook Pro, in Chrome.  Returned NaN.

Comment: ng-camera does not work. Go for webcam-directive

Answer (score 1):

ng-camera needs secured access in chrome browser, add "https://" + url link to access webcam.

Comment: for localhost no need, chrome will allow webcam for localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sajan and davidcondrey.. Now i got it. i refered this following link and get a expected output.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos